# Central limit theorem variance?

Tags: statistics

I was working off of an example in my book and I got confused as to why the n^2 turned into n? [image]

Comment: Because $\mathrm{Var}(S_n)=\mathrm{Var}(X_1)+\dots+\mathrm{Var}(X_n)=n\sigma^2$.

Comment: Ohhh, okay! Thank you so much!